# Migrating to Google maps from iOS maps

Tags: ios, annotations, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an app in the app store which I use iOS/ Apple maps. Now with google maps sdk 1.1 I decided to migrate form Apple maps to Google maps. Is there an easy way to do this without re-writing most of the code?

Note: I currently use custom classes for overlays, pins, and map settings.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: I've used neither API, but my experience says "No, there is no easy way without re-writing parts of your code".

Comment: unfortunately you have to rewrite your code. Maybe you can wait also for somebody to write magical code for migration. When the time come probably iOS 8 has been released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easy way, you have to rewrite yourself.

Comment: You might also find that not all features are supported by the new SDK - eg the current version has limited overlay support, it is quite different to the overlay support in Map Kit.